# Concatenate old value with new one

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, conditional-statements, concatenation

I have a note table and a propal table and my trigger allows after insertion to write what is in my "note_value" field of the note table in my note_public field of my propal table or of my facture table. however the trigger overwrites the value of note_public each time, which I don't want. I would like it to be added, so that it is concatenated.[image of note table][1]
[image of propal table][2]
(when the visibility is 1 this a public note)

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.visibility = 1) THEN
        IF (NEW.item_type = 'propal') THEN
            UPDATE anas01_propal SET note_public = new.note_value WHERE(rowid = new.item_id) ;
        ELSEIF (NEW.item_type = 'facture') THEN
            UPDATE anas01_facture SET note_public = new.note_value WHERE(rowid = new.item_id) ;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmbQA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ct8.png
```

Comment: anas01_facture? is not mentioned in question text. Please add Create trigger code ,add table definition sample data and expected outcome as text to the question. Also CONCAT function seems appropriate..

Comment: Is this as simple as `SET note_public = CONCAT(old.note_value, new.note_value)` or maybe with a space between `CONCAT(old.note_value, ' ', new.note_value)`